# SQL: Alternating values of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm trying to get a interesting thing to happen, and haven't been able to really get it to work.

So, my query:

```
SELECT a.lead_id
,a.status
,a.[user]
, a.list_id
, a.last_local_call_time
, a.owner
  FROM [LEADS].[dbo].[LDS_VICIDIAL_LIST] a
  inner join leads.dbo.LDS_CONTACT_STATUS b on a.[status]=b.[status]
  where list_id in ('2557','2562','2559') and Dialable='Y' and a.status<>'5NI' and a.called_since_last_reset = 'n'
  order by a.last_local_call_time
```

and basically what I am trying to do is get it to display 1 record from list 2557, 1 record from list 2562, and 1 record from 2559 and repeating as such.

Comment: You need to share the sample data and the expected output. Also you need to tell what issue you are facing with this query.

Comment: Refer this link: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.lead_id
,a.status
,a.[user]
, a.list_id
, a.last_local_call_time
, a.owner
  FROM [LEADS].[dbo].[LDS_VICIDIAL_LIST] a
  inner join leads.dbo.LDS_CONTACT_STATUS b on a.[status]=b.[status]
  where list_id in ('2557','2562','2559') and Dialable='Y' and a.status<>'5NI' and a.called_since_last_reset = 'n'
  order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.list_id  order by a.list_id)
```

Got me what I wanted.